# Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland

Tags: xorg, wayland

I'm unable to login with Wayland (I'm using lightdm) because of the following error. If I switch to Xorg then everything is fine.

```
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: Dependency failed for GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: Dependency failed for GNOME Wayland Session.
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: Dependency failed for GNOME Shell on Wayland.
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland.
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: gnome-shell-wayland.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd-logind[1168]: Failed to restore VT, ignoring: Bad file descriptor
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation gnome-shell[2021]: Failed to create backend: No GPUs found
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation gnome-shell[2021]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': GDBus.Error:System.Error.EBUSY: Device or resource busy
bře 17 11:05:31 k-workstation systemd[1746]: Starting GNOME Shell on Wayland...
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I don't know how to fix this.